# Cypress throws Authorisation Bearer undefined and not passing the token

Tags: javascript, cypress

While running the Cypress test, receiving `The response we received from your web server was: > 401: Unauthorized` and cypress displays `Authorization": "Bearer undefined"` in the error details. 
While debugging, the beforeEach > loginToPortal() method is returning valid token successfully. Not sure why the token is not passing to the `deleteTestCompanies` method. It would be of great help if someone could shed some light on this issue ?

Following is the error received

The request we sent was:

```
Method: GET
URL: https://somesite.com/api/Companies
Headers: {
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Authorization": "Bearer undefined",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"
}


beforeEach(
        "Login to web Portal and Navigate to some Page",
        function() {
          cy.server();
          cy.loginToPortal().then((response) => {        
            cy.deleteTestCompanies(this.bearerToken);        
            cy.setTokens({ token: this.bearerToken });
          });
          cy.visit("/stateprofile");
        }
      );



  support/index.js
   import "./commands";
   import "./apiCommands";
```

// Below functions are in "apiCommands.js " file;

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getCompanies", token => {
  cy.request({
    url: "/api/Companies",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }).then(response => {
    var matchedCompany = [];
    const companies = response.body;
    companies.forEach(function(element, index) {
      if (companies[index].name.includes("test-")) {
        matchedCompany.push(companies[index].id);
      }
    });
    cy.wrap(matchedCompany).as("testCompanies");
  });
});



  Cypress.Commands.add("deleteTestCompanies", token => {
  cy.getCompanies().then(companies => {
    companies.forEach(function(element, index) {
      cy.request({
        method: "DELETE",
        url: `/api/companies/${companies[index]}`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-type": "application/json"
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have passed the `token` inside the `cy.getCompanies(token)` method and resolved the problem. Also `console.log("InsideCompanies:" +token)` the token inside the loop.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("deleteTestCompanies", token => {
  cy.getCompanies(token).then(companies => {
    companies.forEach(function(element, index) {
    console.log("InsideCompanies:" +token);
      cy.request({
        method: "DELETE",
        url: `/api/companies/${companies[index]}`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-type": "application/json"
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```